# RecyclerView with ToolBar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I'm new to material design and every time i try to use RecyclerView every thing gose wrong..

can any one know what is the problem ?

**Main Activity class**

```
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;

 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toool);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
 }
```

**Main Activity layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toool"
        layout="@layout/app_tool" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.example.hothyfa.recyclerandmore.Recycler"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toool"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/rere" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Recycler fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recye"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Recycler class**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Recycler extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private MyRecyeAdapter adapter;
    private View view;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rere, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recye);

        adapter = new MyRecyeAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        return view;
    }

    public static List<info> getData() {

        List<info> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int photos[] = { R.drawable.images, R.drawable.dreamsmal, R.drawable.images, R.drawable.dreamsmal };
        String users[] = { "Hothyfa", "Marwan", "Jamal", "Alaa" };

        for (int i = 0; i < photos.length && i < users.length; i++) {

            info current = new info();
            current.iconId = photos[i];
            current.Names = users[i];
            data.add(current);

        }
        return data;

    }

}
```

**RecyclerView Adapter class**

```
import android.content.Context;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;

import java.util.List;

public class MyRecyeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyeAdapter.myholder> {

    List<info> data = Collections.emptyList();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyRecyeAdapter(Context context, List<info> data) {

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;

    }

    @Override
    public myholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);
        myholder holder = new myholder(view);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(myholder holder, int position) {

        info current = data.get(position);

        holder.imageProfile.setImageResource(current.iconId);

        holder.UsersName.setText(current.Names);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class myholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageProfile;
        TextView UsersName;

        public myholder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            imageProfile = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            UsersName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        }
    }

}
```

**custom row layout (for the RecyclerView)**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/images" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Large Text" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and the **data class for the Recycler**

```
public class info {

    int iconId;

    String Names;

}
```

**Toolbar layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/primarycolor" >  
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Note:**  I have put this in the build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
```

and rebuild the app.

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hothyfa.recyclerandmore/com.example.hothyfa.recyclerandmore.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment



                            at 


          app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)

                                at 
              \\\\\\\android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.hothyfa.recyclerandmore.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue, in your `onCreateView` of `Recycler`

```
recyclerView= (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recye);
```

change it to:

```
recyclerView= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recye);
```

Comment: @HothyfaAl-khateb, I found the issue now, I updated the answer, please check.

Comment: man it worked but without the Recyclerview only the toolbar 
and this message

08-17 10:33:00.143    2431-2431/? E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: man it finally worked .... thank you   thank you  thank you  thank you  thank you  thank you  thank you :) :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
  try to edit this     

   <fragment
     android:id="@+id/fragment"
     android:name="com.example.hothyfa.recyclerandmore.Recycler"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/toool"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  />
```

Comment: no still an error

 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hothyfa.recyclerandmore/com.example.hothyfa.recyclerandmore.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" > 
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#2196F3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.hothyfa.recyclerandmore.Recycler"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toool"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/rere" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the toolbar have it's own layout
there is no problem with the toolbar  but when i add the RecyclerView it start the errors ... i will add the tool bar layout
and thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

You can see these two links [How to hide/show toolbar in response to scrolling on Android](http://xmodulo.com/hide-show-toolbar-scrolling-android.html) and [Recyclerview with Cards example in Android with AppCompat (V7)](http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2014/10/recycleview-and-cardview-in-android.html)

Do lemme knw in any concern